# How to make decision on a hypothesis if the p-values of t-test and F-test are not similar

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test

I have to variables X (continuous) and Y (binary with two value 0 and 1). When I ran the t-test and F-test with critical value of 0.05, I got the following results

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Xa and Xb
t = -6.1225, df = 467.26, p-value = 1.954e-09
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.099588 -4.163655
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 40.45062  46.58224 


    F test to compare two variances

data:  Xa and Xb
F = 0.84335, num df = 587, denom df = 262, p-value = 0.09878
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6833098 1.0323080
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          0.843345
```

Since the p-values of the two tests were contradictory (one significant, the other not), what should I do: reject and don't reject the null hypothesis that the two variables were not associated? In general, what test (t or F) is more accurate?

Comment: These do not test the same hypothesis. The t-test is a test of mean equality, while the F-test is a test of variance equality. What do you want to test?

Comment: What are you trying to find out from your data? What are these two Xs and the Y measuring?

Comment: @Dave, I wanted to test whether the two variables (one continuous, the other binary) were associated, that is, if being in certain value range will be less exposed to a condition. An example is whether `Age` will influence the `Survival` in the `titanic` dataset. In my case, `Weight` and `Disease`. Thanks

Comment: Is it fair to say that you want to know if the distribution of `age` is the same for each level of `survival`? If so, in what sense do you want to know if the distributions differ? Just means? Just variances? Both? Any difference?

Comment: @Dave, I guess if two samples came from 2 different distribution, then their respective means and variances would be different? So, if t-test says they are from 2 different distributions but F-test says otherwise, what conclusion can be made then?

Comment: Since the two tests test different aspects of the distributions, there is no reason why they should agree. In fact, if the two distributions differ in mean but not variance, then, assuming a test at the $0.05$-level for statistical significance, the tests got it right.

Comment: I see. That seems sensible. Thanks, Dave! By the way, if so, instead of using t-test or f-test, should I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test instead to draw conclusion whether the two variables are associated?

Comment: Happy to help! // You might consider tidying up your question to make it clear what you're asking (it's mostly clear from the comments, but the question should be clear) and then posting a self-answer based on our chat. An advantage of posting a self-answer is that the community will comment on an incorrect answer, giving you an opportunity to catch if you have made a mistake.